# deepnest app image worked on Ubuntu 17 but not on 20.04

Tags: desktop-apps

The app image `deepnest` (a cad programme) will not work in Ubuntu 20.04. It worked in an earlier version (Ubuntu 17).

I have tried the gui and some command line things but nothing so far works.  (Ps I have limited terminal skills!)
Hi sorry its ubuntu 18.10 downloded, unziped rightclick and choose run it works, do same thing in 20.04, the blue icon spins but it does not run, one other reply has tried on thier pc and it works, so possibly a problem with my pc, Graphics card? in integrated graphics intell four core processor.
I have since tried other distros(based on ubuntu 20.04) and none of them will run this app image, has anyone run a different app image sucessfully with the latest ubuntu,my other thought is maybe although i have ticked the execute box perhaps this is getting over riden by the system for security reasons, but i do not know how to check this, any ideas?

Comment: The deepnest appimage is no longer available at AppImageHub.

Comment: Hi. Please edit your answer and add the exact commands you have tried, and their output. Try to re-download the file, it may be corrupt. Also, make sure to download from the official page (may be deepnest.io ?!). Happy fiddling.

Comment: I just checked. The Linux download on their site is a .zip and the AppImage is inside said zip. Executing it gave the option to add it to your menus and then it opened up and ran just fine. To execute it, I just double clicked on it and chose execute. I didn't even have to chmod +x.

Comment: Ubuntu 17?   No such release, so if that detail is important, you should clarify what you mean. Ubuntu server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* format in nature, and *yy* or *snap* based releases only come out in even years (eg. Ubuntu Core) so no *snap* based releases occurred in 2017.

Comment: hi all sorry nabout version miss information, it was actually ubuntu 18.10, i down load it(deepnest.io)  had to right click and choose run, and it works, however with the latest ubuntu 20.04 do same thing  but wont run, but do see the little icon spinning, but does not open, all the other options available dont work, tried checking to see if programme execute is on yes it is.

Comment: Same problem for me. Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Downloaded & unzipped Deepnest-1.0.5-linux.zip today from Deepnest.io. Made the Deepnest-1.0.5-x86_64.AppImage executable but when i click run nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an incompatability between the library versions of pango and harfbuzz on Ubuntu 20.04. One solution is downloading old versions of the pango libs to the same directory as the AppImage. The process is described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589993/pango-error-harfbuzz-version-too-old